# Change Nitgen enroll interface

Tags: fingerprint

I have a C# application to capture fingerprints using nitgen nbioapi. I am using the enroll method to guide the user to capture the finger, now i need 3 samples of this finger but repeat the enroll method 3 times is confuse to the user.
Somebody has the same issue?  I need a good idea but im going to anywhere.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was a bit similar but I didn't use the UI that nitgen launch to enroll, verify, etc. I used the SDK to go through all the process. You can create your own UI with your own buttons to make the enroll easier to your custormers. I think that's a better solution instead of using the nitgen's UI.
There are many differents ways to do it: you can make a java application, an applet, a windows application in C#, an ASPX app, and so on. There is documentation to reach that.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your solution. In my scenario, i removed the enroll UI and use the capture UI, besides the simple interface, gives me the autonomy to get 3 samples of the same finger. Was the best solution that i found for my project.